# CMake target with sibling folders

Tags: c++, cmake

My project structure is the following:

```
root
-CMakeLists.txt
----exec
-----CMakeLists.txt
-----src
------a.cpp
------a.h
----lib
-----CMakeLists.txt
-----src
------b.cpp
-----inc
------b.h
```

Exec target depends on `lib` target. My main CMakeLists.txt is just the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(FOO CXX)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(exec)
```

In the CMakeLists.txt of the library I use add_library() and I use add_executable() in the exec folder. The problem is that the executable can't find the library and I don't know how to say in the exec CMakeLists.txt that another target exist called lib which is a library to use. I think I'm missing something in the project configuration.

Lib CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(BASIC CXX)

add_library(BASIC src/b.cpp)

set(HEADERS_FILE_DIRS inc)

include_directories(${HEADERS_FILE_DIRS})

#Linking
target_link_libraries(BASIC pthread)
```

Exec CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(EXEC CXX)

add_executable(EXEC src/a.cpp)

set(HEADERS_FILE_DIRS src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/inc)

include_directories(${HEADERS_FILE_DIRS})

set_target_properties(EXEC PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "EXEC")

find_library(BASIC_LIBRARY BASIC HINTS <ABS PATH HERE>/lib)
#Linking
target_link_libraries(EXEC pthread ${BASIC_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: attach lib/CMakeLists.txt and exec/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please, **show the code** instead of *describing* it.

Comment: I added the information needed

Comment: Remove find_library line and use target_link_libraries(EXEC BASIC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you can simply link the `BASIC` CMake library target.  Because it was created earlier in the *same* CMake invocation, CMake already know of its existence and will link it properly.

In addition, (if you can upgrade your CMake to at least 2.8.11) you can apply the `lib/inc` include directory **directly** to your `BASIC` library target using [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories). Use the `PUBLIC` scoping argument here to propagate these include directories to consuming CMake targets. This way, you can avoid mentioning the `lib/inc` directory in your `exec/CMakeLists.txt` file altogether:

In `lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(BASIC CXX)

add_library(BASIC src/b.cpp)

set(HEADERS_FILE_DIRS inc)

# Assign this include directory to the target as a build AND usage requirement.
target_include_directories(BASIC PUBLIC ${HEADERS_FILE_DIRS})

# Linking
target_link_libraries(BASIC PUBLIC pthread)
```

In `exec/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(EXEC CXX)

add_executable(EXEC src/a.cpp)

set(HEADERS_FILE_DIRS src)

include_directories(${HEADERS_FILE_DIRS})

set_target_properties(EXEC PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "EXEC")

# Linking BASIC to EXEC, which propagates the 'lib/inc' include directory
# and the 'pthread' library linkage to EXEC also.
target_link_libraries(EXEC PRIVATE BASIC)
```